# Можно ли в JpaRepository задать поле сортировки в параметре?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-jpa, order

У меня есть метод (интерфейса расширяющий JpaRepository) в котором я хочу указать поле сортировки через параметр. Возможно ли это стандартными средствами используя нативный запрос?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM movie ORDER BY ?3 LIMIT ?2 OFFSET ?1",
        nativeQuery = true)
public List<Movie> getAllMoviesIntervalAndSort(Integer begin, Integer limit, String order);
```

Сейас сортировка не отрабатывается, если указать поле явно в запросе то работает отлично.

Comment: а зачем вообще писать нативный запрос? если у jpa есть поддержка пагинации

Comment: конечно, и через натив и через hql, что передается в 3 параметре и имя колонки можно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имена колонок и порядок сортировки не могут передаваться JDBC-параметрами ([см. англ. версию](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430208/using-a-prepared-statement-and-variable-bind-order-by-in-java-with-jdbc-driver)). Однако `spring-jpa` позволяет обойти это ограничение, т.к. создаёт каждый запрос динамически. Для указания сортировки просто достаточно просто передать дополнительный параметр с типом [Sort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Sort.html). К примеру:

```
public List<Movie> find(Sort order);
```

Таким же образом можно сделать страничный (учитывая сортировку) запрос, используя для этого параметр с типом [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html)

```
public Page<Movie> find(Pageable pageable);
```

Как правильно заметил @Tsyklop не следует писать нативные запросы, т.к. в твоём случае для этого нет необходимости. Достаточно лишь писать имена методов в `JpaRepository` согласно [правилам](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts). К примеру, если допустить, что у тебя в классе `Movie` есть поле `name`, то метод поиска по этому параметру с сортировкой выглядел бы так.

```
//поиск по имени содержащему name
public List<Movie> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);

//поиск по имени содержащему name, отсортированный по колонке name
public List<Movie> findByNameContainingIgnoreCaseOrderByName(String name);

//поиск по имени содержащему name, динамически отсортированный в соответствии с Sort 
public List<Movie> findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name, Sort sort);
```